# Date format validation

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id, sfdc-styleguide

i need to verify the date format in if condition,

date is coming in "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"(2015-15-10 00:00:00) format from java, i need to validate date format in if condition, if date is not in this format , i need to display error message " invalid date format

Ex :

```
for( obj aa: listrec)
  {
     if(obj.date != null && check date format above)
   {

     obj.errr= ' invalid date format or empty"

    }
}
```

Can any one please explain me how can i validate date format in salesforce.

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `DateTime` doesn't seem to have a "parseISO" method that parses ISO-formatted dates, so you can't take advantage of something like that.  The obvious solution here seems to be regex:

```
if(String.isNotBlank(obj.date) &&  
   Pattern.matches('\\d\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d \\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d', obj.date))
```